# Caliburn Micro communication between list and edit viewmodels

Tags: c#, mvvm

I'm new at Caliburn Micro and the MVVM pattern.

I have 3 views (with its corresponding viewmodels):

- `AppView`
- `ClientsView`
- `EditClientView`

`AppView` is my main page with a `TabControl` inside. The child views (WPF `UserControls`) are loaded in new tabs.

In `ClientsView` I have a grid with filtered clients. I select one, and when the `Modify` button is clicked I need to load a new tab with the `editClientView` and load its data. Here is my code:

```
public class EventAggregationProvider
{
    static EventAggregator _eventAggregator = null;
    public static EventAggregator EventAggregator
    {
        get
        {
            if (_eventAggregator == null)
                _eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();

            return _eventAggregator;
        }
    }
}
```

Function on `ClientsViewModel`:

```
public void ModificarCliente()
    {
        AppViewModel myParent = (AppViewModel)this.Parent;
        myParent.OpenTab(typeof(modClienteViewModel));
        EventAggregationProvider.EventAggregator.Publish(_selectedclient);
    }
```

`MainViewModel` `OpenTab` function:

```
public void OpenTab(Type TipoVista)
{
    bool bFound = false;
    if (TipoVista != null)
    {
        Screen myScreen = (Screen)Activator.CreateInstance(TipoVista as Type);
        myScreen.DisplayName = myScreen.ToString();
        foreach (Screen miItem in Items)
        {
            if (miItem.ToString() == myScreen.ToString())
            {
                bFound = true;
                ActivateItem(miItem);
            }
        }
        if (!bFound) ActivateItem(myScreen);
    }
}
```

`EditClientViewModel`:

```
class modClienteViewModel : Screen, IHandle<vw_ClientesFull>
{
    private OhmioService.OhmioServiceClient serviceClient =
        new OhmioService.OhmioServiceClient();        

    public Clientes Cliente { get; set; }

    public modClienteViewModel()
    {            
        EventAggregationProvider.EventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
        Cliente = new Clientes();            
    }

    public void Handle(vw_ClientesFull myClient)
    {            
        Cliente = serviceClient.Cliente_GetById(myClient.ID_Cliente);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange("Cliente");
    }
}
```

So what's your opinion on this? Especially about how I open the edit view (`ClientsView` becomes aware of the existence of `MainWindowViewmodel` and `EditClientViewModel`) from clients' viewmodel, and how I use `eventaggregator` to exchange the selected client between `clientsViewModel` and `EditClientViewModel`.

Answer (score 2):

**Naming**

You should use PascalCase to name methods and types. You do this most of the time, but slip up with `modClienteViewModel`

Your parameters should be in camelCase. Again, you do this most of the time, but slip up with `TipoVista` in your `OpenTab` method.

Avoid Hungarian notation, with a modern IDE it's not necessary, and it just makes types harder to read.

`bool bFound = false;`

should be

`var found = false;`

The same probably goes for `miItem` which can just be `item` without any loss of meaning.

**Var**

Prefer to use `var` in a declaration when the right-hand side makes the type obvious.

e.g.

`AppViewModel myParent = (AppViewModel)this.Parent;`

is obvious because of the cast, so we write

`var myParent = (AppViewModel)this.Parent;`

The reasoning behind this is that if you wanted to change a type, you would have to do so in two places in one line. With `var`, it is only one change.

You should also use `var` when defining the loop variable in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

For the `EventAggregator` property in your `EventAggregationProvider` class you should use the [**?? (null-coalescing) operator**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

Definition:

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

Your `get` will now look much cleaner:

```
public class EventAggregationProvider
{
    static EventAggregator _eventAggregator = null;

    public static EventAggregator EventAggregator
    {
        get
        {
            return _eventAggregator ?? new EventAggregator();
        }
    }
}
```

### Casing:

From the [**Capitalization Conventions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx) on MSDN:

> - Do use PascalCasing for all ***public*** member, type, and namespace names consisting of multiple words.
> - Do use camelCasing for parameter names.